# How to display Google Maps Marker using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display "marker" using `ajax`, I've searched from so many sources from google and I did not find anything.

=================
I have code like below

```
var map;
function initialize(){
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $Lat;?>, <?php echo $Lon;?>);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: center,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('canvas'),myOptions);


        $.ajax({    
            url: 's_imp_open.php',
            success: function(data) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.LATITUDEX, data.LONGITITUDEX),
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
```

and `s_imp_open.php` PHP:

```
include '../../s_config.php';
include '../../s_session.php';

   $SQL = mysqli_query($connect_db, "SELECT * FROM atm_database_mandiri WHERE VENDOR='WIRSBY'");
   $return = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   echo json_encode($return);
```

What should I do for marker to appear in google maps using `ajax`?

Comment: Did you try debugging? Try logging `data` in your AJAX success function to the javascript console to see what it is and post the results here. Looking at the given code, there is no way anyone can help.

Comment: If I were you I'd take out all the PHP code and make sure you can get the marker to show with static coordinates first. Likewise access your server side URL and make sure the output JSON is as you expect. Debugging is slow and time consuming and unfortunately SO can't help you with that.

Comment: Could you provide a sample response from your server? and add it to your post

Answer (score 0):

It seems your implementation is correct, the only thing is missing is to parse the returned data to json.

Here's how you do it:

On your success callback function, parse the returned data to json. You could do something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.LATITUDEX, data.LONGITITUDEX),
           map: map
    });
}
```

Check this **[JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)** to learn more.

**OR**

By adding **dataType='json'** into your ajax request property like this:

```
$.ajax({    
   url: 's_imp_open.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
           // your map code here     
   }
});
```

As per **[Jquery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**:

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string).